# Graphical Representation of array Sorting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting

Does anyone know of a program that visualizes array Sorting in vb.net (Bubble sort,selection sort etc)? Pointers to how I could implement one myself would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this java applet](http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/index.html). It contains complete source code that might inspire you for your own vb.net equivalent.